# How do I send an HTTP response without Transfer Encoding: chunked?

Tags: java, servlets, jetty, chunked-encoding

I have a Java Servlet that responds to the Twilio API. It appears that Twilio does not support the chunked transfer that my responses are using. How can I avoid using `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`?

Here is my code:

```
// response is HttpServletResponse
// xml is a String with XML in it
response.getWriter().write(xml);
response.getWriter().flush();
```

I am using Jetty as the Servlet container.

Comment: What is your Application Server / Servlet Container?

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try setting the [Content-length](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#setContentLength%28int%29) before writing to the stream. Don't forget to calculate the amount of bytes according to the correct encoding, e.g.:

```
final byte[] content = xml.getBytes("UTF-8");
response.setContentLength(content.length);
response.setContentType("text/xml"); // or "text/xml; charset=UTF-8"
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

final OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
out.write(content);
```

Comment: `setCharacterEncoding` is probably not necessary since you are writing raw bytes. content type should include encoding: "text/xml; charset=UTF-8".

Comment: Thanks @zhong.j.yu, updated the answer with your suggestion... User can either set the charset directly with the MIME type or use [setCharacterEncoding](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#setCharacterEncoding(java.lang.String)) which will override the Content-type header.

Answer (score 7):

I believe that Jetty will use chunked responses when it doesn't know the response content length and/or it is using persistent connections.  To avoid chunking you either need to set the response content length or to avoid persistent connections by setting "Connection":"close" header on the response.

Comment: Beat me to it. @Adam, if my code works, please accept cmbaxter answer.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly, now _that_ is classy SO etiquette

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly I will up-vote cmbaxter's answer. But, I was really looking for a code sample that showed what content length to set, so your answer is better despite the fact that both are correct, therefore I will accept yours.

Comment: In my case `Connection: close` suppresses chunking, but then Jersey isn't supplying `Content-Length`, even though my `MessageBodyWriter` returns a non-negative `getSize`. I can set it myself, but then if the response is gzip-encoded, my `Content-Length` will be wrong and Jersey removes it.

Answer (score 1):

The container will decide itself to use Content-Length or Transfer-Encoding basing on the size of data to be written by using `Writer` or `outputStream`. If the size of the data is larger than the `HttpServletResponse.getBufferSize()`, then the response will be trunked. If not, `Content-Length` will be used.

In your case, just remove the 2nd flushing code will solve your problem.